# How to read with timeout without making bash consider it an error?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a read_user_input.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set -e

prompt="bla? [Y/n] "

while true; do
    read -p "$prompt" -n 1 -s -t 3 reply
    case $reply in
        ""|Y|y) echo "bla!!!"; break;;
        N|n) echo "no bla :( you suck"; break;;
        *) ;;
    esac
done
```

Works as I expected - i.e.

- User inputs "Y" -> bla
- User inputs "y" -> bla
- User hits Enter -> bla
- Timeout -> bla

However, when adding `set -e` - the read ends with error > 128.

From `read --help`:

> ```
> Exit Status:
> ```
>
> > The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out
> > (in which case it's greater than 128), a variable assignment error occurs,
> > or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.

What would be the best way to overcome this?

1. adding `|| true` seems not right, as it would hide any real errors.
2. I also don't want to remove the `set -e`.
3. One other thing I thought about was handling it in `trap` but that seems like an overkill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding `|| true`, set the `$reply` to `y` if there was a timeout:

```bsh
    read -p "$prompt" -n 1 -s -t 3 reply || {
        err=$?
        if (( $err > 128 )) ; then
            reply=y
        else
            exit $err
        fi
    }
```

Comment: I used it a bit differently so it would match my switch case

Comment: I updated the answer so that the exit code corresponds to the original one, not the one coming from `$? > 128`.

Comment: I think my answer gives the same outcome

Comment: Try changing `read` to `XXXread` and see what exit code you get from both the versions.

Comment: my version exists, which is ideal

Comment: Yes, but with code 1 instead of 127.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack where is used command substitution which forks a subshell where `-e` is not enabled.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

prompt="bla? [Y/n] "

while true; do
    case $(read -p "$prompt" -n 1 -s -t 3 reply; echo $reply) in
        ""|Y|y) echo "bla!!!"; break;;
        N|n) echo "no bla :( you suck"; break;;
        *) ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: It hides other errors similarly to `|| true`, try running it with `< /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

Using @choroba answer, I changed my switch case into:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

prompt="bla? [Y/n] "

while true; do
    read -p "$prompt" -n 1 -s -t 3 reply || (( $? > 128 ))
    case $reply in
        ""|Y|y) echo "bla!!!"; break;;
        N|n) echo "no bla :( you suck"; break;;
        *) ;;
    esac
done
```